# Using recursion in try catch block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, recursion, try-catch

I have a nodejs script which creates dynamic tables and views for the temperature recorded for the day. Sometimes  it does not create tables if the temperature is not in the normal range. For this I decide to use try catch and call the function recursively. I am not sure if I have done it correctly or if there is another way to call the con.query method, so that tables get created. I encountered this problem for first time in nodejs.

Comment: This won't even run properly as `resolve()` will be undefined in the scope you're trying to call it.  Please post code you've actually tried to run.  If it did run, it would just run an infinite loop since you have no error detection or completion detection that would stop the looping.

Comment: yes it did give an infinte loop i am new to it so havent progressed with using recursion .can you help me out with that?

Comment: Well, to start with, you should ONLY call the function again if you get a specific error.  If you get an acceptable result, you should not continue to recurse.  That's what makes it an infinite loop.  You should be detecting specific conditions and only recursing if those conditions occur.

Comment: so how to approach with it ?

Comment: sometime it doesnt  create tables so how will i detect that

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you have to detect errors and only recurse when there are specific error conditions.  If the problem you're trying to solve is one specific error, then you should probably detect that specific error and only repeat the operation when you get that precise error.

Then, some other recommendations for retrying:

1. Retry only a fixed number of times.  It's a sysop's nightmare when some server code gets stuck in a loop banging away over and over on something and just getting the same error every time.
2. Retry only on certain conditions.
3. Log every error so you are someone running your server can problem solve when something is wrong.
4. Retry only after some delay.
5. If you're going to retry more than few times, then implement a back-off delay so it gets longer and longer between retries.

Here's the general idea for some code to implement retries:

```
const maxRetries = 5;
const retryDelay = 500;

function execute_query(query, callback) {
    let retryCntr = 0;
    
    function run() {
        con.query(query, function(err, result, fields) {
             if (err && err is something we should retry for) {
                  ++retryCntr;
                  if (retryCntr <= maxRetries) {
                      console.log('Retrying after error: ', err);
                      setTimeout(run, retryDelay)
                  } else {
                      // too many retries, communicate back error
                      console.log(err);
                      callback(err);
                  }
             } else if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                   // communicate back error
                   callback(err);
             } else {
                  // communicate back result
                  callback(null, result, fields);
             }
        });
    }

    run();
}
```

The idea behind retries and backoffs if you're going to do lots of retries is that retry algorithms can lead to what are called avalanche failures.  The system gets a little slow or a little too busy and it starts to create a few errors.  So, your code then starts to retry over and over which creates more load which leads to more errors so more code starts to retry and the whole things then fails with lots of code looping and retrying in what is called an avalanche failure.

So, instead, when there's an error you have to make sure you don't inadvertently overwhelm the system and potentially just make things worse.  That's why you implement a short delay, that's why you implement max retries and that's why you may even implement a back-off algorithm to make the delay between retries longer each time.  All of this allows a system that has some sort of error causing perturbation to eventually recover on its own rather than just making the problem worse to the point where everything fails.

Comment: the error which comes is unhandled promise rejection warning:ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST PROCEDURE create_live_tick_table does not exist

Comment: @ness - That doesn't sound like something you need to retry for.  It sounds like something you just need to properly sequence your code so that the next database operation doesn't start until the prior one is complete.  You don't show any code that would actually  run that we could base our help on.

Comment: ive added the whole code please let me know

Comment: @ness - I don't know what the `ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST PROCEDURE` error means.  You will need help from someone who knows your database I guess.  Perhaps it means that the stored procedure `create_live_tick_table()` does not exist in your database yet?